# Jquery: calculate volume

Tags: javascript

Took the base of a code from one user and modified a bit. Basically it does what i need - calculates the sum from three values (first two are in meters, third in centemeters). but i would like it to be more simpler. I dont't need "select options" in thickness field - **it must be calculated in centemeters!**.
And second request - **the amount must be in m<sup>3</sup>!**

html:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Width (m)</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="width" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Length (m)</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="length" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thickness (cm)</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="thickness" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="sel">
                    <option>centemeter</option>
                    <option>meter</option>
                    <option>melemeter</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total (m<sup>3</sup>)</td>
            <td id="answer"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

javascript:

```
$("#width ,#length ,#thickness, #sel").on('change keyup keydown', function() {
    var width = $("#width").val();
    var length = $("#length").val();
    var thickness = $("#thickness").val();
    var result = width * length * thickness;
    var select_val = $("#sel").val();

    if (select_val == "centemeter") {
        $("#answer").text(result).append(" cm<sup>3</sup>");;
    } else if (select_val == "meter") {
        result = result / 100;
        $("#answer").text(result).append(" m<sup>3</sup>");;
    } else if (select_val == "melemeter") {
        result = result * 10;
        $("#answer").text(result).append(" mm<sup>3</sup>");
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/0L8s0ngg/)

**update:** i thought this will be an easy task: calculate amount of three numbers - something like `var result = width * length * thickness;` only **thickness** is 1/100 of width and length...

Comment: What is the programming question? Seems to be a basic maths task (offtopic on stackoverflow)

Comment: programming question is: how to create working online calculator for volume calculation? visitor inserts three numbers (width, length, height) and calculator tells him, how much (m<sup>3</sup>) he has to buy. length and width are in meters, height in centemeters and total in m<sup>3</sup>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below solution to my answer. wasn't that complicated, is it?

```
$("#width ,#length ,#thickness").on('change keyup keydown', function () {

            var width = $("#width").val();
            var length = $("#length").val();
            var thickness = $("#thickness").val();
            var result = width * length * thickness;
             result = result/100;
            $("#answer").text(result).append(" m<sup>3</sup>");;

        });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/0L8s0ngg/)